# Can sodium hypochlorite soak all the way through an unglazed ceramic cup and bleach blue paper wrapped around the outside of the cup?

Tags: organic-chemistry

My question is regarding the ionic properties of sodium hypochlorite in house hold bleach. There is a debate among potters whether bleach will kill mold growing on a porous ceramic cup. It is my understanding that sodium hypochlorite cannot penetrate a porous surface of fired clay. Someone did an experiment where they put household bleach in an unglazed cup and allowed it to soak through. There was blue construction paper wrapped around the outside of the cup and the paper turned white after a while seemingly from bleaching. So my question is this: If the ionic properties of sodium hypochlorite will not allow it to penetrate through the cup to the outside, then how did the blue paper wrapped around the outside of the cup get bleached?

Comment: Can you smell a bleach solution?

Comment: It was probably bleached by vapours.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the ionic properties that control the diffusion. Diffusion is a fundamental property of molecules dissolved in a liquid. A bleach solution stored in an unglazed container can potentially diffuse to the wall. The pore size of the material will mainly control the rate of movement of the fluid (viscosity, surface tension etc.) If the pore size and the connectivity channels are very small it will take ages to wet the wall under atmospheric pressure.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. Then why does everything I have read not recommend using household bleach to kill mold growing on porous surfaces such as concrete or drywall. Many sources ... including the Clorox Co. ... say the sodium hypochlorite molecule cannot penetrate into the porous surface to kill the mold hyphae there. It supposedly only kills mold on the surface and leaves the hyphae growing inside alone. So I’m confused by the experiment that suggested that the bleach solution was able to diffuse through the porous, unglazed ceramic cup in a matter of minutes.

Comment: You raise two points: if the unglazed pottery is very porous, it may take minutes, but if the pore size is very small it may take a very long time. I think the key point is time scale of diffusion. Secondly, bleach manufacturers will not assume that people would let their tiles, or concrete soak in bleach for several days. The typical contact time may be minutes.  That time scale may not be sufficient to eliminate the mold embedded deep inside.

Comment: Shouldn't capillarity result in a relatively fast soaking and wetting?  Broken ceramic, as I think to remember, pick up water quite easily.